# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not resolve named type : String

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hbmxml, mappingexception

I try to put some Objects in my MySql Database but I am stuck with the

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not resolve named type : String
```

I tried to isolate the code which throws the exception and it seems there is a problem with my hbm.xml files.

- It throws the exception when I comment out the actual transaction which means data should not be the problem.
- If I comment out all mapping sources and transactions there is no exception.
- Comment out all but one mapping source it throws the exception (tried it with all sourcess).
- I checked, all files are UTF-8 encoding.

---

Of course I will provide more code if you need it. Those are xml files I use:

```
*hibernate log *
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not resolve named type : String
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.interpretExplicitlyNamedType(BasicValue.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$4(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1800)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1682)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1660)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1799)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1785)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:960)
    at problem.Insert.main(Insert.java:39)
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">XXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">XXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        
        <mapping resource = "Alien.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource = "AlienFood.hbm.xml" /> 
        <mapping resource = "AlienSpaceship.hbm.xml" />
        
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Alien.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="problem.Alien" table="alien">
        <meta attribute="class description">
        </meta>
        <id name="aid" type="int" column="aid">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="acolour" column="acolour" type="String" />
        
        <many-to-one name="spaceships" column="spaceship_sID"
            class="problem.AlienSpaceship" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

AlienFood.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="problem.AlienFood" table="alienfood">
        <meta attribute="class description">
        </meta>
        
        <id name="fid" type="int" column="fid">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="fname" column="fname" type="String" />

        <set name="aliens" cascade="save-update"
            table="alien_alienfood">
            <key column="aid" />
            <many-to-many column="aid" class="problem.Alien" />
        </set>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

AlienSpaceship.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="problem.AlienSpaceship" table="alienspaceship">
        <meta attribute="class description">
        </meta>
        
        <id name="sID" type="int" column="sID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="sName" column="sName" type="String" />
        <property name ="sCooless" column="sCoolness" type="String" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```